# Is it possible to install themes on Ubuntu 16.04.1 without any third party software?

Tags: unity, themes

I had the theme pack downloaded, but tutorials on the internet tell me to use third party software such as unity tweak tool.

My ideal solution is to just extract the theme somewhere in the system, refresh some information in the system somehow, and then choose the theme in settings->appearance->theme (like how it is done in Windows).

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is.  All the themes that are to be used by all users in a system are placed in the **/usr/share/themes** folder as subfolders.  So, the only thing you have to do is copy the theme folder in there as root.  The folder name will be the theme name you see in Appearance.

In case you don't see it in Appearance, make sure the correct permissions are given in that theme folder and mainly that it's readable by **others**.

Alternatively, if you want the themes you extract or copy to be available to your account only, you can create a folder named `.themes` in your home folder and copy the theme folders in there.  The dot in the beginning of the name is essential.  One way to create it is to open a terminal window and type:

`mkdir ~/.themes`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , there are several community themes available. You can search through repositories via  this command:

```
 apt-cache search theme | grep theme | less
```

Particularly, I would like to recommend this package:

```
community-themes - desktop artwork by the Ubuntu community
```

Install it via `sudo apt-get install community-themes` . You will need `Unity Tweak Tool` however to switch them, if you don't want to change them via command line.

Answer (score 0):

By moving themes or after download extracting and placing in the `/usr/share/themes` directory is one simple way to install themes on your system, while doing this you need to root permission as you are trying to install theme package on system. To uninstall any theme you just have to remove the folder of that theme:

```
sudo rm -r "name of theme folder"
```